# Ruby on Rails redirect to view on successful AJAX load for slow controller action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect, spinner

In Ruby on Rails, what is the correct way to render an AJAX 'spinner' while waiting for a slow controller action, and then redirect to the correct view when complete?

Considering the attempt below:

Controller

```
# app/assets/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def slow_action
        sleep 3 # Take a nap
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js {render js: "window.location = '#{slow_action_path}';"}
            format.html {}
        end
    end
end
```

The index page with jQuery to render the spinner div:

```
<!-- app/views/static_pages/index.html.erb -->
<h1>Index Page</h1>

<li><%= link_to "A link to the slow action", slow_action_path, :remote => true %></li>

<div id="spinner">
    <p>Loading... please be patient.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#spinner").hide(); // Hide the spinner initially

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(r, s) {
        $("#spinner").show();
    });


    $(document).ajaxStop(function(r, s) {
        $("#spinner").fadeOut("fast");
    });
</script>
```

And, for what it's worth, the slow_action's view:

```
<!-- app/views/static_pages/slow_action.html.erb -->
<h1>This is the slow action</h1>
```

The problem (I think) is that `window.location` call is simply calling the same action again, and the server is sleeping all over again.  What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

We use `spawn` aka `spawnling` for this - https://github.com/tra/spawnling

You spawn off a thread to handle the slow stuff and then redirect to a different action/template which periodically checks whether it's done yet.  This template is displayed in modal-style box which hovers over the page.  We test whether the app is done yet by the creation of temp files, and tracking the pid of the spawned thread, but you could use the database instead if you wanted.

Your problem is that you're trying to **do the thing** and **see if the thing is finished yet** in the same place.  You should have a different, generic, action to see if a task is finished yet, which takes some parameter which will allow it to test whether the task is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually quite easy.  I just load the link in the normal way (without `:remote => true`), and simply have a piece of jQuery code to display a spinner on the `index` page when the link is clicked.

The controller is much simpler:

```
# app/assets/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def slow_action
        sleep 3 # Take a nap before rendering the view
    end
end
```

And the index page becomes:

```
<!-- app/views/static_pages/index.html.erb -->
<h1>Index Page</h1>

<div id="the-menu">
    <li><%= link_to "A link to the slow action", slow_action_path, :id => "slow-link" %></li>
</div>

<div id="spinner">
    <p>Loading... please be patient</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#spinner").hide(); // Hide the spinner by default
    $("#the-menu").show(); // But show the menu

    $("#slow-link").click(function (event) {
        console.log("onClickEvent() called")
        $("#spinner").show();
        $("#the-menu").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Note that the link is assigned an id (`slow-link`), and the jQuery at the bottom of the page defines the `click` event for that link.